# Spring Scheduling framework

Tags: spring, scheduling, spring-3, scheduled-tasks

Hi I am new to Spring framework itself and I am implementing Spring scheduling framework. I have written my class and methods to be executed.

now all i did was add the below code to spring.xml

```
     <bean id="schedulerInstance" class="com.package.SchedulerService">
    <property name="maxAgeTableOne" value="30"/>
    <property name="maxAgeTableTwo" value="30"/>
    <property name="maxAgeTableThree" value="30"/>
</bean>


  <task:scheduled-tasks scheduler="taskScheduler">
    <!-- An interval-based trigger where the interval is measured from the completion time of the previous task.  -->
    <task:scheduled ref="schedulerInstance" method="cleanuptableone" cron="0 0 23 1 * ?  " />
    <task:scheduled ref="schedulerInstance" method="cleanuptabletwo" cron="0 0 23 1 * ?  "/>
    <task:scheduled ref="schedulerInstance" method="cleanuptablethree" cron="0 0 23 1 * ? " />

</task:scheduled-tasks>

<!-- Defines a ThreadPoolTaskScheduler instance with configurable pool size. -->
<task:scheduler id="taskScheduler" pool-size="1"/>
```

From what I think it is now scheduled to run every month but it does not seem to work or run anything? is there something else i should be doing?

the SchedulerService class above is pure java class and does not have any spring related or scheduling related stuff in it.

Please guide what else I should be doing here to make the class a scheduled class.

Thanks,
SS

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure this is necessarily an answer but I compared your implementation to that of a working implementation I have:

```
<task:scheduler id="scheduler_project"
    pool-size="1" />
<task:scheduled-tasks scheduler="scheduler_project">
    <task:scheduled ref="execObj" method="start" cron="0 0-59 * * * *" />
</task:scheduled-tasks>
```

There doesn't seem to be much difference other than the "?" in the cron schedule.

Might I suggest you slim your test case to run a simple command on a more frequent iteration to make sure no code issues come into play?  Might expose where the underlying problem is.

Comment: so even though i change the frequency of the cron job to run every minute i do not see anything in the log , I have log statements all over. Should i use any annotations like @Scheduled or something like that so that spring know that the particular is scheduled to run? thanks.

Comment: how are you running this code, from a main or deployed to tomcat or equivalent?  If from a main, what code loads the spring context?  If from tomcat, are you using the ContextLoadListener to initialize?